# Atributo 'data-*' html - Reglas de creación

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

¿Se puede crear los atributos data seguido de un número, `data-0 = "mexico"`?

O algo como esto:

```
data-data1 = "mexico"
```

La idea es recuperarlos a través de una iteración y así ahorrarse de escribir atributo por atributo.

Comment: Hola, ¿usando JavaScript, jQuery?

Comment: En realidad los dos, estaba haciendo unas pruebas y quise mejorar el code, y mucho mejor que saberlo hacer de ambas maneras

Comment: Perfecto, te deje un ejemplo con JS y jQuery.

Comment: Stack no me dejó ponerle a respuesta útil por no tener más de 15 puntos de reputación pero dejo en claro que me fue útil. ¡Muchas gracias de nuevo!

Comment: Por cómo has planteado la pregunta pensaba que querías saber si podían usarse números en los atributos data-* y no como acceder a ellos. Dejo un link sobre eso por si te es útil: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/dataset

Comment: De hecho si, mi duda era si se podía usar números y el link que has dejado me lo ha dejado claro: "The name of a custom data attribute in HTML **begins with data-**. It must contain only letters, **numbers** and the following characters: dash (-), dot (.), colon (:), underscore (_) -- but NOT any ASCII capital letters (A to Z)".
Igual supe como hacerlo de otras maneras en lugar de iterarlos. Todo duda resuelta acerca de ello. ¡Muchas Gracias!

Comment: Mejor mira la respuesta de @AlvaroMontoro que es una traducción de la especificación HTML.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Respondiendo a tu pregunta original: *¿Se puede crear los atributos data seguido de un número, data-0 = "mexico"?*, la respuesta la puedes encontrar en la [especificación de HTML5 para los data-atributos](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#embedding-custom-non-visible-data-with-the-data-*-attributes) (traducción mía):

> *3.2.5.9 Embeber datos personalizados no visibles con los atributos `data-*`*
>
> Un **data-atributo personalizado** es un atributo fuera de cualquier namespace cuyo nombre comienza con la cadena "`data-`", tiene al menos un caracter después del guión, es [compatible con XML](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/infrastructure.html#xml-compatible), y no contiene ninguna [letra ASCII en mayúsculas](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/infrastructure.html#uppercase-ascii-letters).

Entonces para que el nombre del data-atributo sea válido debe:

1. Empezar con `data-`.
2. Tener al menos algún carácter después del guión.
3. Que sea un nombre compatible con XML. Para que un nombre sea compatible con XML debe:

   - No contener el carácter `:`.
   - Las tres primeras letras no pueden ser `xml` (en cualquier variación de mayúsculas/minúsculas).
   - Debe cumplir con los [nombres definidos de XML](https://www.w3.org/TR/xml/#NT-Name).
4. No contener mayúsculas.

Aunque según la definición de XML el primer carácter de un nombre no puede ser un número, esa regla no afecta a los data-atributos porque realmente el primer carácter será la "d" de "data-" y no el primer carácter después del guión.

Teniendo eso en cuenta, **el atributo `data-0` es válido, tanto como `data-data1`**; y de hecho, ambos pasan con éxito el [validador de HTML del W3C](https://validator.w3.org/).

Comment: En el enlace que he puesto yo en mi comentario dice que se admiten los dos puntos `:`. *It must contain only letters, numbers and the following characters: dash (-), dot (.), colon (:), underscore (_) -- but NOT any ASCII capital letters (A to Z).*
Aunque la documentación de MDN suele ser buena la especificacion es la que manda y el validador da error usando `:`

Comment: @blonfu interesante. Tampoco tomaría el validador como una verdad absoluta (a veces falla). Voy a mandar un mensaje a los de MDN a ver si responden sobre lo del `:`

Comment: Muchas gracias por la respuesta! He usado eso para crear atributos con una iteración, y los recupero desde jquery usando lo de @blonfu.

Me han ayudado para evitar estar cambiando el code cada que actualizo.

Answer (score 8):

No es necesario usar numeración para iterar sobre ellas, tampoco es necesario iterar atributo por atributo usando sus nombres. Las versiones recientes de jQuery (si es que estás tratando de hacerlo usando jQuery) permiten obtener todos los atributos `data-*` llamando simplemente al método `data()` sin parámetros:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    var atributos = $("#prueba").data();
    console.log(atributos);

    // Uno de ellos
    console.log(atributos.pais);

    // Para iterar sobre los atributos
    $.each(atributos, function(key, elem) {
        console.log(key + ' -> ' + elem);
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<h1 id="prueba" data-id="1" data-ciudad="Lima" data-pais="Peru">
    Prueba
</h1>
```

Con JavaScript puedes usar el atributo [`dataset`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/dataset) del elemento:

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) { 
    var element = document.getElementById("prueba");
    var data = element.dataset;
    console.log(data);
 
    // Para iterar sobre los atributos
    for (key in data) {
        console.log(key + ' -> ' + data[key]);
    }
});
```

```html
<h1 id="prueba" data-id="1" data-ciudad="Lima" data-pais="Peru">
    Prueba
</h1>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias! Lo de Jquery es genial, no tenia idea de ello, Fue mejor que quererlo iterar