# Cómo capturar un atributo data de varios inputs

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

Estoy desarrollando una cuadrícula de productos en los que el usuario debe elegir una cantidad limitada. El problema es que tengo que capturar el producto escogido y el nombre del producto. Para ello he creado un card colocando los valores que va a ver el usuario, el usuario puede elegir las cantidades desde unos botones de aumentar y disminuir productos y al final un botón para enviar todos los productos a elección.

[image: cuadricula de productos]

Este es el código html

```
<?php if ($query_wines->have_posts()) :  ?>
    <div class="row bottle_wine">
        <?php while ($query_wines->have_posts()) :
        $index ++;
        $query_wines->the_post(); ?>
        <div class="col-12 col-md-4 mb-3">
            <div class="card">
                <?php the_post_thumbnail('full', array('class'=>'img-fluid mx-auto d-block w-100' , 'title'=>get_the_title(), 'alt'=>get_the_title())); ?>
                <div class="card-body">
                    <h4 class="card-title text-center typo_title"><?php echo get_the_title() ?></h4>
                    <p><?php the_excerpt() ?></p>
                    <h5><?php var_dump($price) ?></h5>
                    <form action="" id="wine_form">
                        <input type="text" class="post_wine d-none" value="<?php echo $post->ID ?>">
                        <div class="count_quatities d-flex justify-content-center">
                            <button type="button" id="lower" class="lower btn btn-dark-red mr-3" value="Decrease Value">-</button>
                            <input type="number" value="0" min="0" id="number" class="number form-control w-30" data-title="<?php echo get_the_title() ?>">
                            <button type="button" id="upper" class="upper btn btn-dark-red ml-3" value="Increase Value">+</button>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <?php endwhile ?>
    </div>
    <?php wp_reset_postdata();
    endif; ?>
```

Como pueden observar, en el input "number" se está capturando la cantidad que selecciona el usuario y el nombre del producto "data-title", que en este caso es el título.
Para controlar las cantidades elegidas y el producto a elección, he utilizado jquery. aquí está el código

```
var counter = 0
var title = ''
var total = 0

$('.upper').on('click', function() {
    var $qty = $(this).closest('#wine_form').find('input#number')
    var currentVal = parseInt($qty.val());
    if (!isNaN(currentVal)) {
        $qty.val(currentVal + 1);
    }
});

$('.lower').on('click', function(){
    var $qty = $(this).closest('#wine_form').find('input#number')
    var currentVal = parseInt($qty.val());
    if (!isNaN(currentVal) && currentVal > 0) {
        $qty.val(currentVal - 1);
    }
});

$('.number').on('keyup', function() {
    $(".number").each(function() {
        if (isNaN(parseFloat($(this).val()))) {
            counter += 0;
        } else {
            counter += parseFloat($(this).val());
            title = $('#number').data('title');
        }
    });
        console.log(counter + ' - ' + title)
});
```

En un console.log estoy imprimiendo los valores capturados.
La cantidad la captura sin problema, pero en nombre del artículo "title" no lo captura correctamente. pues me muestra el primer producto de la lista.

Agradezco a o los que me puedan ayudar a poder a entender cómo capturar el nombre del producto elegido por el usuario.

Les deseo a todos éxitos en sus proyectos.

**Solución**
Encontré la solución muy fácil.
Solo tenía que utilizar el botón "revise su pedido" para crear una función que iterara sobre todos los input `class="number"` almacenara la cantidad y el "data" en un array así:

```
const total = () => {
var item = $('.number')
var dataTotal = []
var title = ''
var cant = 0
var total = 0

$('#viewSuscription').on('click', function () {

    item.toArray().forEach((e) => {
        cant = parseInt($(e).val())
        title = $(e).data('title')
        
        if (cant > 0) {
            dataTotal.push([cant, title])
        }
    })
    
    console.log(dataTotal)
})
```

}

Gracias a todos por sus aportes y por tomarse el tiempo de responder a mi inquietud.

Comment: que tiene que ver esto con php???

Comment: el PHP omitirlo, porque se están iterando unos datos que se estan trayendo desde WordPress. Por eso no hago enfasis en PHP.

Comment: po reso lo quie de los tags

Comment: Mi problema no es capturar el dato. Mi problema es capturar el dato del input al que se le estan agregando valores

Comment: jamas lo vas a lograr y te explico por que, Tienes graves errores:

Comment: te pregunto saves enviar datos de HTML a PHP??? si no sabes hacer eso correctamente y no lo intentas, jamas lo lograras

Comment: Yo no estoy enviando datos de html a php. solo estoy capturando unos valores que estoy trayendo desde una base de datos por eso son los "echo". No tengo problema al iterar los datos de la db, Porque me está mostrando en pantalla los datos. Mi problema es capturar el "data-title" cuando se le aplique un valor al input.

Comment: no te estoy entendiendo nada ... puedes dar una mejor explicacion detalladamente de que hace tu codigo; que error te sale; que debe de hacer???

Comment: Hola, Bienvenid@ al Sitio, veo que eres nuev@ te recomendaria hacer el [tour] para que conoscas mejor el sitio, He mirado tu post y te comento lo siguiente:, Puedes leer este Articulo [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida, Puedes leer este Articulo [mre], También es importante que sepas que preguntas son mal vistas [help/dont-ask].

Answer (score 1):

No es necesario usar numeración para iterar sobre ellas, tampoco es necesario iterar atributo por atributo usando sus nombres. Las versiones recientes de jQuery (si es que estás tratando de hacerlo usando jQuery) permiten obtener todos los atributos data-* llamando simplemente al método data() sin parámetros:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var atributos = $("#prueba").data();
    console.log(atributos);

    // Uno de ellos
    console.log(atributos.pais);

    // Para iterar sobre los atributos
    $.each(atributos, function(key, elem) {
        console.log(key + ' -> ' + elem);
    });
});


<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<h1 id="prueba" data-id="1" data-ciudad="Lima" data-pais="Peru">
    Prueba
</h1>
```

Esta respuesta fue tomada de la publicación: [Atributo 'data-*' html - Reglas de creación](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/92311/atributo-data-html-reglas-de-creaci%c3%b3n?rq=1)

Comment: cuando encuentras una respuesta previa a una pregunta; deberias solicitar el cierre basado en duplicidad con referencia a la pregunta donde se resuelve el problema... no re-escribir la respuesta.... solo es aceptable cuando venga del sitio en ingles.

Comment: Graicas Uriel por tu ayuda. Entiendo lo que me quieres explicar, pero si te das cuenta en mi código, se debe iterar, porque hay varios input que traen datos. Pero como ya dije anteriormente, el valor que me está trayendo es el del primer input, pero no al que estoy aplicando el valor